# remove objects from array based on the index

Tags: objective-c

I have array of images here i am doing check and uncheck the images finally i have delete button which are the images i check i need to remove the images from array based on the button selection 
here is my code

```
- (IBAction)delete_btn_touch:(id)sender {
     [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    for(int i=0; i<_GalleryimageArry.count;i++){
        _imageV = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) * i/2*0.6, 0, 100, 100)];

        self.Crossbtn =[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(_imageV.image.size.width/2+80,0,20,20)];
        UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unselectimag"];
        [self.Crossbtn setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        _imageV.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        _imageV.image = [_GalleryimageArry objectAtIndex:i];
        [_imageV setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        _imageV.tag = i;
        self.Crossbtn.tag =i;
        [self.Crossbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapMethod:)];
        [_imageV addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        [self.imageV addSubview:self.Crossbtn];
       [self.imageGalleryscroll addSubview:_imageV];
        [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];
    }
    self.imageGalleryscroll.delegate = self;
    index=0;



    self.imageGalleryscroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) * _GalleryimageArry.count/2*0.7, CGRectGetHeight(self.imageGalleryscroll.frame));

    [self.imageGalleryscroll setPagingEnabled:YES];

    [self.imageGalleryscroll setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    self.imageGalleryscroll.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
     [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
}


-(void)deleteImage:(UIButton *)sender{
     btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    self.add_delete_view.hidden =YES;
   self.deleteview.hidden=NO;

    if( [[btn imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselectimag"]])
    {
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Crossimg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setSelected:YES];
        [btn setTag:index];
    }
    else
    {
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselectimag"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        // other statements
        self.selectedimages =@"No";
        image = [self.GalleryimageArry objectAtIndex:index];
        [self.GalleryimageArry addObject:image];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", self.GalleryimageArry);
}
- (IBAction)delete_all_img_btn_touch:(id)sender {
    // self.view (change it with your button superview)
        if (btn.selected) {
           [self.GalleryimageArry removeObjectAtIndex:index];
        }

   //here i need to removeObjectAtIndex:index based on the how many button are selected 
}
```

any one help me to solve this issues
thanks in advance

Comment: What is the issue you are facing while delete?

Comment: not get remove objectes from array

Comment: i need to remove the  [self.GalleryimageArry removeObjectAtIndex:index]; based on how many button selected

Comment: Means, you want to remove all objects from the array? or some objects from the array?

Comment: some objects from array which i selected button

Comment: So simple,, just create a new array, and add object in it in you this if.

if( [[btn imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselectimag"]]){
}

After in your delete_all_img_btn_touch function just make a comparison and delete objects. let me create some code for you as well.

Comment: can u please post the answer

Comment: i send to u dude

Comment: let me check dude

Comment: thank you dude ...

Comment: Check your email bro

Comment: its not working dude

Comment: when select images its not remove adding images from objects

Comment: Bro,, it is just idea,, do something like my code, create a separate array, save object in this when selected and make comparison and delete when delete all button pressed.

Comment: bro i need to to delete the particular values which i select

Comment: i f i unselct it wont remove from the array

Comment: can you please send me whole code?

Comment: i confused lot how to do thats please update some code dude based on my requirements

Comment: ok give me second

Comment: i send to u bro

Comment: Please don't share code by email, but post it here so it is beneficial for all readers. Question for @ammu: do you show your images in a `UITableView` ?

Comment: no showing imagegs in scrollview

Comment: Do you have a specific reason not to use a `UITableView`? These are made for showing lists of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code, where you want to clear the back stack of controllers.

```
-(void)clearStack
{
    NSMutableArray *navigationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers];
    [navigationArray removeAllObjects];
    //[navigationArray removeObjectAtIndex: 2];
    self.navigationController.viewControllers = navigationArray;
}
```